# Quantidade máxima de conexões simultaneas com banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou utilizando uma solução de monitoramento de sistemas e observo que em horários de pico o sistema possui cerca de 1500 conexões simultâneas. A partir deste dado, procurei e não consegui encontrar onde posso verificar o limite de conexões simultaneas com o banco de dados.

Então, como posso configurar/verificar o limite de conexões com o banco de dados? O gerenciamento do pool de conexões é de responsabilidade do banco de dados ou da aplicação? Fora isto, o que pode interferir no limite deste valor?

Comment: MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: Rodrigo, a aplicação utiliza os dois bancos de dados, mas o que está chegando a 1500 é o SQL Server

Comment: Vinicius o que vou dizer não é a resposta, mas supondo que seja uma aplicação web, é provável que em uma requisição você faça várias conexões sem necessidade, é só uma teoria. Talvez analisando o código pudesse diminuir pela metade (claro que não conheço o projeto portanto posso estar falando besteira).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O limite de conexões simultâneas pode depender:

- da versão do seu banco;
- do limite configurado;
- da capacidade do hardware;

*Então, como posso configurar/verificar o limite de conexões com o banco de dados?*

O limite máximo do SQL Server é de 32.767 conexões. Você pode conferir o limite configurado no [sys.configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188345.aspx). Lembrando que o limite de conexões no SQL Server é por **instância** e não por banco de dados.

*O gerenciamento do pool de conexões é de responsabilidade do banco de dados ou da aplicação?*

O recurso de pool de conexões é gerenciado pela aplicação. Existem diferentes frameworks ORM que tem sua própria implementação para gerenciamento do pool de conexões (ADO.NET, Hibernate, etc) ou conseguem se conectar a outras bibliotecas de gerenciamento de pool de conexões (c3p0, BoneCp, etc).

Se a aplicação abrir indefinidamente conexões com o banco de dados, sem reutilizar ou fechar as que já abriu, chegará um momento que o banco de dados alcançará o limite configurado ou, o mais comum, deixará o banco de dados gradualmente lento. A abertura de uma conexão com o banco de dados não é um recurso barato.

*Fora isto, o que pode interferir no limite deste valor?*

O mais comum é o banco ficar lento muito antes de atingir o número de conexões máximo configurado, geralmente pela abertura indiscriminada de conexões, conforme explicado anteriormente.